# how to save large files - WAMP server, Database

Tags: database, database-design, wamp, wampserver

I am creating a database on a WAMP server, running locally on my machine for now. I want to organize audio files, I understand I can use BLOB in the database but this is apparently very slow. I thought the best way would be to use a database with a reference to the location of the audio file. How do you achieve this using WAMP server? I have created the database, I need to add a folder of some onto the server. Also is there any other way of trying to get where I want?

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved by using  folder on saved on the server and using webclient class (C#) to upload the file and SQL to alter the database which holds information on that file, including the location in the server.